PC turns on but takes a long time to send any signal
When I press the power button on my tower, my PC lights up. At which point, my monitor goes from stand-by to blue screen showing no signal, like it is about to receive a signal. Then nothing happens and my monitor goes back to stand-by mode.
At first all I had to do was unplug my monitor and plug it back in then somehow it would magically work. Then I decided to try to update the Display drivers, which told me that the drivers were already up to date. I tried forcing it to reinstall the already existing drivers, then now it takes an even longer time to show signal.
Last time I measured the time, it took 4 minutes from me powering up the PC to it showing any signal to my screen.
Already tested out a Different HDMI cable. I am yet to get another monitor to test this out.
Any ideas?
I'm not super savvy when it comes to troubleshooting. I bought this PC prebuilt from ABS.
My PC is a Windows 11,
Intel Core i9 13900K,
Gigabyte GeForce RTX 4070 super,
Mother board is Gigabyte B760 DS3H AC,
Teamgroup T-Force Delta DDR5 RAM 32 GB.
What makes me suspect it is my PC and not my monitor is because when the monitor finally receives any signal, it shows the initial lock screen with the standard windows background and the clock at the top (In hope that makes sense) even though I am constantly pressing buttons and clicking my mouse. Thus, if my PC was operating normally and my monitor was the issue, then when I receive signal, the initial screen would be the one to type in my PIN, since Windows says "press any button to start" then takes you there. I really hope that makes sense.

Does your computer have more than one video connection? If you plug the monitor into one of the other video connections do you get pictures on your monitor sooner? Alternatively, have you tried a different monitor?

It does have more connections but they are all Display Port connections and I don't have  a way to use them at the moment. I do have another monitor I can test it out with. I will try it out and see the results

Your motherboard supports iGPU even though your cpu does not have it (unless you have been conned). You need to go into the BIOS and disable it.

Sounds like your motherboard firmware is configured to prefer a different GPU than what you're currently plugged into, preventing the display from activating until the appropriate driver is loaded by the OS.
Likely, you wish to take advantage of your GeForce GPU. Make sure that your display is plugged into it, and not the iGPU ports that are closer to the top of your motherboard. If you're plugged into the iGPU ports, changing to the discrete GPU's ports will likely be the only step you need to correct the behavior. Though you may wish to disable the iGPU in UEFI/BIOS.
If your display is currently plugged into the GeForce GPU, then you'll want to:

Temporarily switch the display cable to the iGPU
Boot into your UEFI to change settings
Disable iGPU multi-monitor support
Set the motherboard to prefer the PEG or PCIe graphics device
Save settings and reboot
Plug the display cable back into the GeForce GPU

